# How to Put Spacing when SideBar collapse and uncollapse on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, layout, navbar, sidebar

**Im trying to achieve when a sidebar collapse the body will make space for the sidebar and when it uncollapse**

**This is what it looks like when the sidebar uncollapse**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKsWW.png)

**and this is what it looks like when the sidebar collapse**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5j6G.png)

```
import React from 'react';
import SideNav, {
  Toggle,
  Nav,
  NavItem,
  NavIcon,
  NavText,
} from '@trendmicro/react-sidenav';
import '@trendmicro/react-sidenav/dist/react-sidenav.css';

export const SideBar = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <SideNav
        onSelect={(selected) => {
          // Add your code here
        }}
      >
        <SideNav.Toggle />
        <SideNav.Nav defaultSelected='home'>
          <NavItem eventKey='home'>
            <NavIcon>
              <i className='fa fa-fw fa-home' style={{ fontSize: '1.75em' }} />
            </NavIcon>
            <NavText>Home</NavText>
          </NavItem>
          <NavItem eventKey='charts'>
            <NavIcon>
              <i
                className='fa fa-fw fa-line-chart'
                style={{ fontSize: '1.75em' }}
              />
            </NavIcon>
            <NavText>Charts</NavText>
            <NavItem eventKey='charts/linechart'>
              <NavText>Line Chart</NavText>
            </NavItem>
            <NavItem eventKey='charts/barchart'>
              <NavText>Bar Chart</NavText>
            </NavItem>
          </NavItem>
        </SideNav.Nav>
      </SideNav>
    </>
  );
};

export default SideBar;
```

and this on App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import Nav from './components/NavBar';
import Home from './screens/Home';
import Login from './screens/Login';
import Register from './screens/Register';
import SideBar from './components/SideBar';
import { GlobalProvider } from './context/GlobalState';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <GlobalProvider>
      <Router>
          <Nav />
          <SideBar />

          <Switch>
            <Route path='/' component={Home} exact />
            {/* <Route path='/login' component={Login} exact /> */}
            <Route path='/login' component={Login} exact />
            <Route path='/register' component={Register} exact />
          </Switch>
      </Router>
    </GlobalProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I tried adding margin in the body but it dosent look nice when you uncollapse because theres still more space. Sorry if this is not right

I want something like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcSHg.png)

**I'm kinda new and would really appreciate if you could help me
Thanks in advance !!!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [Trend Micro demo page](https://trendmicro-frontend.github.io/react-sidenav/) they do add margins on the content. That is one approach that is already recommended by the module. You can add some CSS transition property so that it is as smooth as the expanding/collapsing of the sidebar. Just add more margin if the sidebar is expanded. Utilize the [`onToggle`](https://github.com/trendmicro-frontend/react-sidenav#properties) event of the sidebar to set the state as needed.

App.js

```
const [sideNavExpanded, setSideNavExpanded] = React.useState(false);

const contentStyle = {
    marginLeft: sideNavExpanded ? "250px" : "70px", // arbitrary values
    transition: "margin 0.2s ease"
};

return (
    <div>
        <SideBar
            setSideNavExpanded={setSideNavExpanded}
            sideNavExpanded={sideNavExpanded}
        />
        <div style={contentStyle}>Some Content</div>
    </div>
)
```

Sidebar.js

```
export const SideBar = ({ sideNavExpanded, setSideNavExpanded }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <SideNav
        onToggle={() => {
          setSideNavExpanded(!sideNavExpanded);
        }}
      >
      ...
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-trend-micro-sidebar-fjo9r?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thank you it worked but i have a prpoblem when responsive with mobile how to disable the click of the hamburger menu

Comment: it looks like this

Comment: and also it has been having horizontal scroll how to fix those

Comment: You can opt to detect the viewport inside a [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) via [resize event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event). Adjust your margins as necessary - I'd execute viewport detection on-component-mount as well. You can also opt to add `disabled` attribute to the hamburger button on small screens (style as necessary) and set `sideNavExpanded` to `false` so it is collapsed on small screens if you do not want it expanded

Comment: can you do it on your answer

Comment: I've updated the [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-trend-micro-sidebar-fjo9r?file=/src/App.js) example I've written. By default, I initialized `sideNavExpanded` to `true` for responsiveness demo. Drag the demo window until it is below 375 width to see sidebar collapse. Read the comments on the code for more insight. Hope this helps

Comment: i will check later